# How do I customized the action parameter in TbActiveForm widget of yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Hi I would like to know is there any way to customize the action parameter in TbActiveForm of booster widget in yii?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Action parameter works like CActiveForm

For example:

```
       <?php
       $form = $this->beginWidget(
           'TbActiveForm', array(
           'id' => 'contact-form',
           /**
           * @var mixed the form action URL (see {@link CHtml::normalizeUrl} for details about this parameter).
           * If not set, the current page URL is used.
           */
           'action' => array('/front/contact'),
           'method' => 'post',
           )
       );
       ?>
```